# Top menu block not working in my Magento 1.9.0.1

Tags: blocks, ce-1.9.0.1, menu

I am changing in `app/code/core/mage/page/block/html/Topmenu.php` in my magento but I cannot see result. but when i change in `topmenu.phtml` file then it displays changes.
what is the issue? I am sure the `Topmenu.php` is the block file but menu still display. I don't know how is it possible. I am also trying in `Navigation.php` in `Mage/catalog/block/navigation.php`. it's also now working. how is it possible?

Means when I change code in `Topmenu.php` file's `_gethtml()` function, for example I write `echo "hello";` then doesn't show. But when I am changing in `topmenu. phtml` file and  write any code it displays in the navigation.

In `header.phtml` I call top menu using

```
<

?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topMenu') ?>



 topphml.phtml file code



 <?php echo "hello"; ?>
    <?php $_menu = $this->getHtml('level-top') ?>
    <?php if($_menu): ?>
    <div class="nav-container">

        <ul id="nav">
            <?php echo $_menu ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <?php endif ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

In Magento 1.9.0.1 the Topmenu `_gethtml()` function is deprecated in favour of using a renderer.phtml

If your editing `_getHtml()` and the changes are not being show I think your theme is probably using this `renderer.phtml` file - rather than editing `_getHtml()` in Topmenu you probably need to edit /`page/html/topmenu/renderer.phtml`.

Answer (score 0):

you need to copy the file

`app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Navigation.php`

and place it in

```
app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Navigation.php
```

and find the function `renderCategoriesMenuHtml`, this one is directly called from `topmenu.phtml` file so you need to start work from here. However, almost all the functions in `Navigation.php` are involved in creating the Menu so you need to work in them accordingly.

Comment: Hello MTM,  My file is topmenu.php. i am delete topmenu.php file and navigation.php file and menu still display. how it possible.

Comment: what do u want to do? do you want to remove the menu?

Comment: i want change topmenu strucute of navvigation(menu).

Comment: enable template and block hints, and you will get the correct file names that are involved.

Comment: it diplay `Mage_Page_Block_Html_Topmenu`

Comment: i am change in topmenu.php block file but not working ? my question is that.

Comment: can you post the topmenu.phtml file by editing your question.

Comment: i display in what i code ot html in topmenu.phtml but when i chanage in topmenu.php file then it topmenu.php change not working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17121/discussion-between-jaydipsinh-parmar-and-mtm).

Answer (score 0):

AS you are saying that your topmenu.php changes is not showing changes.
For that you have to check that from which block its calling if its overridden by other module than it can't show your changes
You can check which block is called from topmenu.phtml:

```
<?php echo get_class($this); ?>
```

Above line print the block class.